# 2 different libelf.h and libdwarf.h in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, debugging, elf

In FreeBSD 10.3 there are 2 libelf.h, `/usr/include/libelf.h` and `/usr/local/include/libelf/libelf.h`. And they have different defines, such as `enum Elf_Cmd`.

Also there are 2 libdwarf.h, `/usr/include/libdwarf.h` and `/usr/local/include/libdwarf.h`. And they have different defines, such as `dwarf_init()`.

Why?
What's the difference?
Which one should I use?

=== update ===

Thanks for forquare, now I know that there are 2 libraries both named `libelf`. I have tried them, and they worked both.
However I still have problom with `libdwarf`.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <libdwarf.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = open("memleax", O_RDONLY);

    Dwarf_Debug dbg;
    Dwarf_Error error;
#if USR_LOCAL
    int res = dwarf_init(fd, DW_DLC_READ, 0, 0, &dbg, &error);
    if(res != DW_DLV_OK) {
            printf("dwarf_init error: %s\n", dwarf_errmsg(error));
            return -1;
    }
#else
    int res = dwarf_init(fd, DW_DLC_READ, &dbg, &error);
    if(res != DW_DLV_OK) {
            printf("dwarf_init error: %s\n", dwarf_errmsg(&error));
            return -1;
    }
#endif
```

If using system-lib:

```
cc  debugline.c -o debugline   -lelf -ldwarf
```

it goes wrong with:

```
dwarf_init error: ELF error : I/O error [dwarf_init(738)]
```

If using usr-local-lib:

```
cc -D USR_LOCAL -I /usr/local/include/ debugline.c -o debugline -L /usr/local/lib/ -lelf -ldwarf
```

it goes wrong with:

```
dwarf_init error: DW_DLE_ELF_BEGIN_ERROR 27 a call to elf_begin(... ELF_C_READ_MMAP... ) failed
```

How should I use `libdwarf`?

=== update

Ok, I know....

There are 2 `libdwarf`. I should ignore system-lib, and install the non-system-lib by pkg, and use it.

There are 2 `libelf`. I should use the system-lib, and can't install the non-system-lib by pkg.

Comment: What is the output of `pkg which /usr/local/include/libdwarf.h` ?

Comment: /usr/local/include/libdwarf.h was installed by package libdwarf-20130207

Answer (score 2):

The one located in `/usr/include/libelf.h` is included with FreeBSD while `/usr/local/include/libelf/libelf.h` has been installed by you/the system admin most likely as part of a dependency for another package—perhaps the one included in base wasn't at the correct version, or maybe the one installed is from a difference source altogether.

You can use either, but if you move to a system that doesn't have `/usr/local/include/libelf/libelf.h` you will need to install it via ports or `pkg`.